# Accessing inner JSON field in Scala

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have JSON string as

```
{
  "whatsNew" : {
    "oldNotificationClass" : "WhatsNewNotification",
    "notificationEvent" : { ..... },
    "result" : {
      "notificationCount" : 10
      .....
    }
  },
  ......
  "someEmpty": { },
  ......
}
```

I am trying to get `notificationCount` field using `json4s` in `Scala` as follow but `notificationCount` is coming as empty for all. Any help?

**UPDATE**
Also if some pair is empty how can I handle empty condition and continue to loop?

Function returning JSON string from file

```
def getData(): Map[String, AnyRef] = {
  val jsonString = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/sample.json")).getLines.mkString
  val jsonObject = parse( s""" $jsonString """)
  jsonObject.values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, AnyRef]]
}
```

Code to get fields

```
val myMap: Map[String, AnyRef] = MyDataLoader.getData

for((key, value) <- myMap) {
  val id = key
  val eventJsonStr: String = write(value.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]] get "notificationEvent")
  val resultJsonStr: String = write(value.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]] get "result")
  //val notificationCount: String = write(value.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Map[String, String]]] get "notificationCount")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use path and extract like so:

```
val count: Int = (parse(jsonString) \ "whatsNew" \ "result" \ "notificationCount").extract[Int]
```

you will need this import for the `.extract[Int]` to work:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
```

To do it in a loop:

```
parse(jsonString).children.map { child =>
  val count: Int = (child \ "result" \ "notificationCount").extract[Int]
  ...
}
```

Comment: I want to do inside Map for loop. not in getData().

Comment: It's better to retain the JSON AST - or tree - as you traverse through the tree, in order that you can do paths with subtrees. See update.